# programmatically check checkbox asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, webforms, web-controls

Im trying to loop through a collection and create checkboxes for each item in the collection. I check if a bool is true and want that checkbox to be checked. But I cant seem to get this to work. What am I missing here?

```
var checkboxList = new CheckBoxList();

foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
{
    if (answer.CorrectAnswer)
    {
        var cbItemOrd = new CheckBox
        {
            Checked = true, 
            Text = answer.AnswerText + " Correct Answer"
        };
        checkboxList.Items.Add( cbItemOrd.Text );
        cbItemOrd.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        checkboxList.Items.Add(answer.AnswerText);
    }

}
div.Controls.Add(checkboxList);
```

I get the "correct answer" text out on the correct field so the loop works. If I need to use "FindControl" or something, how do I do that with programmatically created objects?

Thanks alot!

Comment: You are only adding the checkbox's text to the list. Where is the checkbox being added to the view?

Comment: ...you're adding `cbItemOrd.Text` (a `String`) to the list, not `cbItemOrd` (the `Checkbox`).

Comment: Oh i see that now. How do you add the object instead?

Comment: Use `ListItem`. and set the `Selected` property.

Comment: It works, thanks! But how do I add spacing between the items now? when they are in a listitem that is also generated dynamically?